# Identity and Access Management for Heroku Application

Tags: heroku, cedar, identity-management

My identity and access management tool of choice is OpenAM utilising their container based policy agents, this approach is not possible however using the Heroku Celadon Cedar stack  -- at least it doesn't look possible to me (www.heroku.com)

What is the recommended way to enforce authentication and authorization for cedar deployed apps?

Thanks
/W

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the OpenAM access management tool. However if your application requires authentication or authorization then I would recommend to contact third party services linke TeleSign for their [identity and access management](http://www.telesign.com)  sevices.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your users in your own database, or used a hosted identity service like [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/) (disclaimer: it's awesome).

If you end up using something like Stormpath, you'll basically work with a REST API to create, manage, and authenticate users.